# Sort Python dict by datetime value

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary like this:

```
{
   'apple': datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'orange': datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>),
   'raspberry': datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
}
```

What is the best way to sort the dictionary by the datetime values? I am looking for a list output with the keys in order from most recent to oldest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could sort the keys like this:

```
sorted(dct, key=dct.get)
```

See the [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) for an explanation of this and other techniques for sorting.

Answer (score 6):

Bearing in mind that the question asks how to sort *by the datetime values*, here's a possible answer:

```
sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)

=> [('raspberry', datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 9, 0, 0)),
    ('apple', datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 20, 0, 0)),
    ('orange', datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 4, 0, 0))]
```

If you're only interested in the keys:

```
[k for k, v in sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda p: p[1], reverse=True)]

=> ['raspberry', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy, you just do, something like:

```
 from operator import itemgetter
 sorted(a.items(),key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

Comment: you don't need `itemgetter` here since the `get` method of dicts returns values (see @unutbu's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting list of keys as below for dictionary `dict`:

```
[item[0] for item in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda val: val[1])]
```